# Expiration date for items in the past in wordpress - not showing current date

Tags: wordpress, content-expiration

I'm using the following code to hide posts in the past in wordpress (the date is coming from a custom field I've made called date) - problem is its also hiding ones set to today's date as well

```
<?php query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=24&order=desc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=date'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date', true);
if ($date){
$mydate = "$date";
echo date('l, j F, Y', strtotime($mydate));

}
?>
```

Any Ideas how to get it to allow posts where the custom field is todays date?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific answer to your question but there are two plugins that do exactly what you are trying to do.  I've linked them below.

1. Simple Expires 
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-expires/
2. Post Expirator
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-expirator/

Both seem to be exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this..

```
<?php      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//to check against expiration date; 
$currentdate = date("Ymd");
$expirationdate = get_post_custom_values('date');
if (is_null($expirationdate)) {
$expirestring = '30005050'; //MAKE UN-EXPIRING POSTS ALWAYS SHOW UP;
} else {
if (is_array($expirationdate)) {
$expirestringarray = implode($expirationdate);
}
$expirestring = str_replace("/","",$expirestringarray);
} //else
if ( $expirestring >= $currentdate ) { ?>

loop goes in here

<?php } ?>
```

In all honesty I can't remember where I found it - but if someone can neaten it up that would be great!